# javascript prototype inheritance bug

Tags: javascript

superclass has a 'container' property.

when subclasses inherit from superclass, the 'container' property is shared between subclasses.

How is it implemented that each subclass has its own copy of its superclass, with all its properties.

```
 var a = function() {
 };

 a.prototype.ax = function() {
     this.container = [];
 }

 var b = function() {
 a.call(this);
 }

 b.constructor = b;
 b.prototype = Object.create(a.prototype);

 b.prototype.ax = function() {
 a.prototype.ax();
     this.container.push('b');
 }

 var c = function() {
 a.call(this);
 }

 c.constructor = c;
 c.prototype = Object.create(a.prototype);

 c.prototype.ax = function() {
     a.prototype.ax();
     this.container.push('c');
 }


 var bi = new b();
 var ci = new c();

 bi.ax();
 ci.ax();

 // why bi container gets overriden?
 console.log(bi.container);
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YZVPF/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
 b.prototype.ax = function() {
     a.prototype.ax();
     this.container.push('b');
 }
```

To call the superclass function, you need to it like so:

```
b.prototype.ax = function() {
     a.prototype.ax.call( this );
     this.container.push('b');
 }
```

Otherwise you are simply calling `ax` with `a.prototype` as the context (value of `this`).